# How do I return information to another file?

Tags: python

So, I'm trying to make something simple:

```
shopping_list = []
print("Enter 'done' to stop adding items.")

while True:
   new_item = input("> ")

   if new_item.lower() == "done":
       break
   shopping_list.append(new_item)
   print("Here's your list:")

   for item in shopping_list:
      print(item)
```

Can I, instead of printing this, return the list to another file in order to display that file?  I'm new to this and am not sure if that's possible (though everything is possible with code, right?).  My goal is to get the list to display, and to be saved so I can access it anytime.

Comment: Write a function. Have the function `return` the list. Have the code in the other file call the function.

Comment: So you mean you want to write the list to a text file? If so look at [this](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python) website. Otherwise could you please clarify your question

Comment: Thank you, @Professor_Joykill, that was informative.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you'll need to put your code inside a function. Or else, you won't be able to "return" anything.

```
def foo():
    ....
    return shopping_list
```

So, your code would be something like:

```
def foo():
    while True:
       new_item = input("> ")

       if new_item.lower() == "done":
           break
       shopping_list.append(new_item)

    return shopping_list
```

And, you'd call your function like this:

```
my_shopping_list = foo()
```

Once the function returns, `my_shopping_list` is a list of shopping items, you are free to do as you please.

Also notice I removed the print statements from your loop. Please feel free to add them in if you need them, but I assume that's what you didn't want.

---

Now, when you say file, I assumed you just meant to somewhere else inside the same program. But if you do indeed want to call this function from another python script, here's what you'll do:

`A.py`:

```
def foo():
    ... # entire function definition here
```

`B.py`

```
import A

my_shopping_list = A.foo()
```

Create two python scripts. The first one houses your `foo` function. The second one calls it.

---

Alternatively, if you want to print your shopping list to an *actual file* (taking your words literally here), you'd do:

```
foo():
   ...
   with open('cart.txt', 'w') as f:
       for i in shopping_list:
           f.write(i + '\n')
```

This writes your items to a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to run the list to a text file outside of your python script you can do the following:

```
outfile = open(file, "w")
CODE
outfile.write(shoppping_list)

outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
def func():
    shopping_list = []
    print("Enter 'done' to stop adding items.")

    while True:
        new_item = input("> ")

        if new_item.lower() == "done":
            break
        shopping_list.append(new_item)

    return shopping_list
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Here's your list:")

    outfile = open('test.txt', "w")
    shopping_list = func()

    # outfile.write(shopping_list)

    for item in shopping_list:
        # print(item)
        outfile.write(item + "\n")

    outfile.close()
```